# CSS not loading in Django project?

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I'm new to Django but have been tasked with doing the front-end work for the project. I've been researching how exactly to load the css files and the methods I've found just aren't working. Here is the .html file layout:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <title class="title"> NHSEE Homepage </title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/homepage.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1> NHSEE </h1>
    <a class="btn btn-1" href="/judges">Judges</a>
    <br>
    <a href="{% url 'students' %}">Students</a>
    <br>
    <a class="btn btn-1" href={% url 'scoring-sheet' %}>Scoring Sheet</a>
    <br>
    <a href="/students">Students</a>
    <br>
    <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
</div>
```

Here is the layout of the files (not sure if its where I'm putting the files that causing the issue) [image]
Any help is greatly appreciated. Its very frustrating as I've done frontend work professionally before and can't get a stupid css file to show up.

EDIT: The settings.py file [image]

Comment: Please also include the trailing part of your `settings.py` file - we need the details about `STATIC_URL` and `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: Ah, I'll make an edit

Comment: [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code. Please read the [site guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions, particularly on using [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) and [sample code](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as editing the question to replace the images with text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, first you need to have `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your `settings.py`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')]
```

Then go ahead and move all your **assets** (css, js, fonts, ...) to a directory called `assets` beside `manage.py` (not inside your apps)

as an example, let's say you have `assets/css/home_page.css`; you should use `{% static 'css/home_page.css' %}` in your templates to access that (omitting the `assets` directory).

That was the basic idea, you can name those directory as you need.